# Change a SWF audio file

Tags: flash

I am not familiar with flash, and I would like to change an audio file from an annoying noise to a silent (aka, blank) file. Before you ask "why use it at all" - It is used for an online chat client, and invokes a Jquery error if the file is not present.

[The current file](http://digital-diy.com/forum/mchat/error.swf).

It would be outstanding if someone could whip-up an error.swf file that is silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really feel like hosting a file anywhere, so just copy these bytes into a hex editor:

```
46 57 53 01 19 00 00 00 30 0A 00 A0 00 01 01 00 43 02 FF FF FF 40 00 00 00
```

Comment: Fabulous. Now I don't mean to be rude, could someone verify this is OK to use?

Comment: Although there's no way I can really prove it to you, the first three bytes are the SWF signature (FWS, SWF backwards). The byte after that is the version. If you look up ActionScript on Wikipedia, you'll see that version 2 was the first version to have any kind of scripting support. Therefore, there's no way there could be any malicious script in there. You can read [the SWF file format specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf), too, if you're really paranoid.

Comment: Heh, I believe you mate. This day and age it's worth at least asking :)  Thank you for your time +1 for an answer!